# How to add a value of the variable at the beginning of a csv file

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk

I have a CSV file (sample1.csv) in which I need to add the value of x as the first column of the entire CSV.
My code looks like this,

code:

```
x=24 feb 20 12:29:30
awk -v d="$x" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$1=d; print}' sample1.csv > sample2.csv
```

The above one replaces the first field of the CSV with x value instead of appending x value at the beginning.

sample1.csv

```
TV,Sony,40,smart
TV,LG,32,smart
```

sample2.csv [expected output]

```
24 feb 20 12:29:30,TV,Sony,40,smart
24 feb 20 12:29:30,TV,LG,32,smart
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is nonsense, but can't you just add it back on the = replacement: {$1=d, $1; print}?

Comment: AND I get `bash: feb: command not found` (as I would expect) when I execute your code `x=24 feb 20 12:29:30x=24 feb 20 12:29:30`. You need to dbl-quote your assignment value, i.e. `x="24 feb 20 12:29:30x=24 feb 20 12:29:30"` . Please learn to vet your code at https://shellcheck.net **before** you post it here. (be sure to include the appropriate `#!/bin/bash` (or other) as the first line when you paste there) . Good luck.
`

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` to prepend variable before `$1`;

```
awk -v d="$x" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$1=d OFS $1} 1' file.csv
```

Or use this `awk` with `sub` function call that replaces line start with variable value and your field separator (comma):

```
awk -v d="$x" -F, '{sub(/^/, d FS)} 1' file.csv
```

```
24 feb 20 12:29:30,TV,Sony,40,smart
24 feb 20 12:29:30,TV,LG,32,smart
```

Answer (score 1):

easier with `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^/24 feb 20 12:29:30,/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You are soooo close.  Try this:

```
x="24 feb 20 12:29:30"
awk -v d="$x"  'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {print d,$0 }' sample1.csv > sample2.csv
```

Comment: Removed FS as per @EdMorton

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is

```
mlr --csv -N put '$value="24 feb 20 12:29:30"' then reorder -f value input.csv >output.csv
```